# vuejs problem change route get userChoice in localstorage but push on the profile route before getting new userChoice?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

the problem is that on click I increments the new userChoice according to the user chosen but it pushes on the profile route before retrieving the new userChoice click.

what to do here is my template I will put everything in the same function change use the push at the end but it does not work either then I do 2 functions but it does not work either what is the solution ??

```js
<template>
  <section
    class="stopPadMarg container-fluid d-md-flex justify-content-between"
  >
    <div class="py-5 stopPadMarg bg-primary col-md-1">
      <img
        src="../assets/image/icon.png"
        width="60px"
        class="rounded-circle"
        alt="logo"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="largeur80">
      <form class="justify-content-center form-inline py-3 my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input
          v-model="searchKey"
          id="search"
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
      </form>
      <div>
        <h3
          class="backPrimaire opacity mx-1 text-primary bordurePost bordureRond"
        >
          <b-icon-chevron-double-down
            class="mr-5 my-1 pt-1 text-secondary"
            animation="cylon-vertical"
            font-scale="1"
          ></b-icon-chevron-double-down>
          Vos collegues
          <b-icon-chevron-double-down
            class="ml-5 my-1 pt-1 text-secondary"
            animation="cylon-vertical"
            font-scale="1"
          ></b-icon-chevron-double-down>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="hauteur">
        <div class="mt-5 d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div
            v-for="(user, id) in filteredList"
            v-bind:key="id"
            class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-content-center"
          >
            <div @click="changeUser(user)" class="cursor">
              <img
                @click="changeRoute"
                v-if="user.image_url !== null || ''"
                :src="user.image_url"
                width="100px"
                height="100px"
                class=" justify-content-left bordureProfil
          rounded-circle"
              />
              <img
                v-else
                src="../assets/image/icon.png"
                width="100px"
                class=" justify-content-left bordureProfil rounded-circle"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class="mt-2">
                {{ user.nom.toUpperCase() }}
              </h5>
              <h6 class="mb-3">{{ user.prenom.toLowerCase() }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="py-5 stopPadMarg bg-primary col-md-1">
      <img
        src="../assets/image/icon.png"
        width="60px"
        class="rounded-circle"
        alt="logo"
      />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      searchKey: "",
      postes: [],
      users: [],
      user_id: localStorage.getItem("userId"),
      userChoice: localStorage.getItem("userChoice"),
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.postes = [];
    this.users = [];

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/postes")
      .then(
        (response) => ((this.postes = response.data), console.log(response))
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .then(
        (response) => ((this.users = response.data), console.log(this.users))
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .then(
        (response) => (
          (this.userDef = response.data.find((user) => {
            return user.id;
          })),
          console.log(this.userDef)
        )
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/user/${this.user_id}`)
      .then(
        (response) => (
          (this.userConnect = response.data), console.log(this.userConnect.id)
        )
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/commentaires")
      .then(
        (response) => (
          (this.comments = response.data), console.log(this.comments)
        )
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  },

  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.users.filter((user) => {
        return user.nom.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchKey.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async changeUser(user) {
      await localStorage.removeItem("userChoice");
      await localStorage.setItem("userChoice", user.id);

      this.$router.push(`/profil/${this.userChoice}`);
    },
    async changeRoute() {
      await this.$router.push(`/profil/${this.userChoice}`);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

and the picture here

if I press a second time on the same profile it gives it to me if I return to the colleagues page but not if I change profile there is an empty page

[image]
[image]

[image]

here picture of the routes path

[image]

in fact the route does not change profile and remains on 58 here c the profile of that which is connected and if we change number on the route it launches a page page so this is the problem with the path of the route that the we see in the browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your code it's obvious why you'd get an empty page when changing routes. Let me explain:

Your routes say this:
Register a route /profil/${userChoice} (which is a value read from localStorage).
This route definition is only read once, at page intialisation. So, when your page loads only /profil/58 will be defined, /profil/59 wont.

What you are probably looking for is route parameters:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

You'd want the number part of this url to be dynamic and respond to changes.

So, instead of reading the value from localStorage, you would write:

```
{ 
    path: '/profil/:user_id', 
    name: 'ProfilUser', 
    ...
}
```

Now when your Profil components is initialized instead of accessing localStorage you read the provided value as follows:

```
created() {
    var userChoice = this.$route.params.user_id;
}
```

(note it is also possible to get this param as a prop, consult the vue-router docs on how to do this)

Another thing you need to keep in mind is that you need to respond when this parameter changes. Your component will not be refreshed/remounted.

To respond to parameter changes you can do the following:

```
watch: {
   '$route.params.user_id'() { 
       this.reloadAllStuff();
   }
}
```

I would recommend to not use localStorage for this use case, let the URL parameter be the main source of truth.

Further reading:

- https://qvault.io/2020/07/07/how-to-rerender-a-vue-route-when-path-parameters-change/

Comment: but created() function i put to the component  amis or in the file route ??? and the watch where i put this property ??

Comment: for the profile I no longer have a problem choosing the profiles.
 but there is still a problem in the navigation component when I am on the profile page and I click on choose find your posts from the profile of another user, it no longer goes to the profile of the user to connect.
 on the other hand on the home page I can enter his profile by clicking on the navigation bar

Comment: Put only 'var userChoice = this.$route.params.user_id;' in the `async created` function in your vue file. Put the watch above the 'async created' function and you will be good to go.

Comment: 107:9  error  'userChoice' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: but userChoice never used in the created

Comment: I put watch in the data and the userChoice var in async created of the template

Comment: Hi Gerald, I put the examples there so you have an idea of how to go about it, you should put it in, adjust it to your situation and play with it a bit, learn how to make it work for you. In this case change 'var userChoice = ' to 'this.userChoice = '